# Want to show calendar inside popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a calendar onclick of image but inside popup window and with calendar I want to show three items
1st--select items to select start or due date 
then 2nd-- calendar 
and 3rd--watch.
and 4th one is submit button once we select submit button it will update all the values which we have selected so far and everthing inside that popup window.

What I have tried is I'm using the datepicker plugin but that plugin is not helping me at all..

and the thing is i had already use some popup plugin in my code when i try to use  same popup it will not open in proper position ...

[image: For Reference]

there are more than 20 buttons are there one by one what i want on click of that open that popup at perfect position as what i shown in fig,, it will take top, left right position properly

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing? At least give some pointers to any errors or problems you faced while implementing the datepicker plugin.

Comment: have look at the image what i wanted for reference

Comment: It's a "calendar." Not a "calender."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a button that when clicked will open a `datetime` picker.

If you have been trying to use the jquery `datepicker`, then you will have to roll your own in order to get the date and time.

Alternatively, you may want to research some `datetime` pickers that are already out there.

For example,
[here is a datetime picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) that may fit your requirements.

Comment: have a look at imgage for reference what im looking for